# Add delay between toggle of the button states (disable and then enable after 5 secs). (Xamarin, c#)

Tags: c#, multithreading, xaml, xamarin

I have a single "Start" button, When I click, the button is immediately disabled and I need a delay of 5 secs before the button is enabled back.

Start Button (enabled) ----Click----> Start Button (disabled) ------Wait for 5secs------> Start Button (enabled).

I am using a button click handler :

I tried the following ways:

---

```
public async void OnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Button button = (Button) sender;
button.IsEnabled = false;
Task taskA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeWork(10000000));
taskA.Wait(5000);
button.IsEnabled = true;
}
static void DoSomeWork(int val)
{
Thread.SpinWait(val);
}
```

---

```
public async void OnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Button button = (Button) sender;
button.IsEnabled = false;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
button.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Does any of those work and whats the easy of implementing the delay(requirement).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace taskA.Wait(5000); with await Task.Delay(5000). Do not forget to add the await keyword, otherwise the method will return immediately, i.e it will not wait 5secs. Also replace System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); with await Task.Delay(5000)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
await Task.Delay(5000);
```